# Problem with with Object object response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Could I get some help here from this response I am receiving?
I am receiving this response from an API call, I try to store the results from screen_results, but when I do attempt to print it out all I get is the [Object object] even when I attempt to stringify it, all I get is "[Object object] can someone help me out here to get the results and put them in a single array?
Thanks

[image: API Response]

Comment: Adding some code to show us what you have tried so far would help. Without that it's near impossible to offer much help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the result of `toString` on the objects, you can either `console.log` the objects directly or `JSON.stringify` them and then `console.log` that.

Either way, you'll get the keys and values of the object instead of `[object Object]`.

Comment: Unless the problem is on the sending side and `[object Object]` is indeed what they were sent.  Then, they'd have to fix the sending side.  Not enough info here for us to have any idea.

Comment: Sure, just thought I'd have a stab at solving this, considering that it's more likely to be a client-side mistake than a bad API (since hosting an API takes skill and money).